# Permissions Error in Starting R Shiny Server

Tags: r, ubuntu, shiny

I had Shiny loaded on my Ubunto 14.04 machine and it was working fine. I just upgraded to 16.04 LTS and now it no longer works. I have reinstalled Shiny and followed the instructions [here](http://deanattali.com/2015/05/09/setup-rstudio-shiny-server-digital-ocean/), to no avail.

I have made a user group called shiny-apps that has read-write permissions for my web apps:

```
owner@shiny-smith:/srv/shiny-server$ ls -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 owner shiny-apps 33 Jul 13  2015 DroughtNet -> /home/owner/Documents/DroughtNet/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 owner shiny-apps 38 Jul 13  2015 index.html -> /opt/shiny-server/samples/welcome.html
lrwxrwxrwx 1 owner shiny-apps 37 Jul 13  2015 sample-apps -> /opt/shiny-server/samples/sample-apps
```

and both 'shiny' and 'owner' are members of shiny-apps group:

```
owner@shiny-smith:/srv/shiny-server$ groups owner
owner : owner adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare shiny-apps
owner@shiny-smith:/srv/shiny-server$ groups shiny
shiny : shiny shiny-apps
```

However, checking the shiny-server still shows a permissions error:

```
owner@shiny-smith:~$ shiny-server
[2016-12-30 14:29:38.608] [INFO] shiny-server - Shiny Server v1.5.1.834 (Node.js v6.9.1)
[2016-12-30 14:29:38.612] [INFO] shiny-server - Using config file "/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf"
[2016-12-30 14:29:38.648] [ERROR] shiny-server - Error loading config: The user 'owner' does not have permissions to run applications as one of the users in 'shiny'. Please restart shiny-server as one of the users in  'shiny'. (/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf:2:1)
[2016-12-30 14:29:38.648] [INFO] shiny-server - Shutting down worker processes
```

and if I add 'owner' to the shiny server config, that doesn't fix the issue:

```
owner@shiny-smith:~$ sudo nano /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf
owner@shiny-smith:~$ sudo systemctl restart shiny-server
owner@shiny-smith:~$ shiny-server
[2016-12-30 14:30:54.580] [INFO] shiny-server - Shiny Server v1.5.1.834 (Node.js v6.9.1)
[2016-12-30 14:30:54.584] [INFO] shiny-server - Using config file "/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf"
[2016-12-30 14:30:54.621] [ERROR] shiny-server - Error loading config: The user 'owner' does not have permissions to run applications as one of the users in 'owner,shiny'. Please restart shiny-server as one of the users in  'owner,shiny'. (/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf:2:1)
[2016-12-30 14:30:54.621] [INFO] shiny-server - Shutting down worker processes
```

Can someone help me figure out where the issue is?

Comment: Can you add `run_as :HOME_USER: shiny;` to the conf file and try?

Comment: @Gopala that didn't work either

Comment: I am noticing you might just be trying to check the status of the shiny server by issuing 'shiny-server' command by itself? In that case, you should try `systemctl status shiny-server`. This works for me on RHEL. I also get the same error when I issue just the `shiny-server` command standalone as that tries to startup the server, which you must be `sudo` to run.